# I need some help understanding the use of a private static variable

Tags: c#, static

I already read up on a few posts here about private static, and I think I somehow got the idea, but I still have to ask for some help on clearing me up on this one.

Currently I am going through a class I didn't write, and I found this at the beginning `private static string x`.

I never came across private static, only public static for constants or similar things.

So now towards my question: What advantage does `private static` have?

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but as far as I understood, it's allowing the variable to only be accessible by methods of this class due to private.
The static part however tells me that that variable is unique and bound to the class, rather than to its objects, so assuming we have 5 instances of the class containing `private static string x`, all 5 instances will always have the same value when evaluating `x`.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct. And that value will only be accessible to the class itself. If either of them change it, it will be changed for all instances that try to access it.

Comment: which is only possible once per appdomain load.

Comment: Another reason for doing this may be that the variable has to be accessed from a static method. A normal variable cannot be accessed from within a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is "global" variable for all objects of this class.

Answer (score 0):

`private static` its useful for encapsulation of variables

for example java like enum

```
class MyEnum
{
    private static List<MyEnum> _values;
    public static Enumerable<MyEnum> Values {get { return _values.ToArray()}} 

    public static readonly FOO = new MyEnum('foo');
    public static readonly BAR = new MyEnum('bar')

    private MyEnum(string s)
    {
      //...
      _values.Add(this);
    }
}
```

as you can see we have `_values` variable which is not accessible from other class. But other class can obtain read-only copy via Values.

Comment: This is true about private variables - static or not.